# Invalid number during insert query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert, number-formatting

**Insert SQL**:

```
INSERT INTO TB.SDL
  (
    SOL_ID,
    LOCKER_TYPE,
    LOCKER_NO,
    CUST_ID,
    STAFF_FLG,
    RENT_AMOUNT_CHARGED,
    PERCENT_RENT,
    START_DATE,
    LCHG_TIME,
    LCHG_USER_ID,
    RCRE_TIME,
    RCRE_USER_ID,
    DEL_FLG,
    BANK_ID
  )
  VALUES
  (
    '42' ,
    'KUK' ,
    'KU19' ,
    '00080' ,
    'N',
    '49.50' ,
    '33,33',
    sysdate,
    sysdate,
    'AAY' ,
    sysdate,
    'AAY' ,
    'N',
    '01'
  );
```

**Error**:

> -ORA-01722:Invalid Number

```
INSERT INTO TB.SDL
  (
    SOL_ID,
    LOCKER_TYPE,
    LOCKER_NO,
    CUST_ID,
    STAFF_FLG,
    RENT_AMOUNT_CHARGED,
    PERCENT_RENT,
    START_DATE,
    LCHG_TIME,
    LCHG_USER_ID,
    RCRE_TIME,
    RCRE_USER_ID,
    DEL_FLG,
    BANK_ID
  )
  VALUES
  (
    '42' ,
    'KUK' ,
    'KU19' ,
    '00080' ,
    'N',
    49.50 ,
    '33,33',
    sysdate,
    sysdate,
    'AAY' ,
    sysdate,
    'AAY' ,
    'N',
    '01'
  );
```

**Table description**:

[image]

> -1 Row inserted

I want to insert 33,33 in percent_rent column but it doesnt let me do so .
Can any please why case1 is failing ?I have inserted the column description image as well.

Comment: '33.33' is a string, not a number.

Comment: You're passing a string instead of a number. Also, try with a point as a decimal separator (instead of a comma): 33.3

Comment: In european system we use 33,33 as separator and not 33.33 and if I enter 33,33 without the quotes it will be  an issue as sql will consider it to separate numbers.

Comment: @Abid You must explicitly mention the **NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS** to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table description shows that the column `PERCENT_RENT` is **NUMBER(9,6)** data type. The problem is that you are inserting the value `'33,33'` which is  a **string** and not a **number**.

Insert the number as it is, no need of **single-quotation marks**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A NUMBER(9,6));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(33.33);

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

> I want to insert 33,33 in percent_rent column but it doesnt let me do so

The format is controlled by **NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS** parameter.

You could specify it at **session level** or at **individual SQL level**.

If you want to **insert the number** in your **desired format**, then you must use **TO_NUMBER**.

For example,

```
SQL> INSERT INTO t (a)
  2    VALUES
  3    (
  4      TO_NUMBER('33,33','9G999D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
  5    );

1 row created.

 SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
     33,33
```

Now, to **display the number** in your **desired format**, use **TO_CHAR**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(A,'9G999D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') my_number_format
  2  FROM t;

MY_NUMBER
---------
    33,33
```

Comment: In european system we use 33,33 as a decimal separator and not 33.33 and if I enter 33,33 without the quotes it will be  an issue as sql will consider it to separate numbers.

Comment: @Abid You must explicitly mention the **NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS** to do so. Added few examples, see the answer.

Comment: Thanks ,But i would like to ask that why below case is working when i am giving '33' in string format
insert into TB.SDL(SOL_ID,LOCKER_TYPE,LOCKER_NO,CUST_ID,STAFF_FLG,RENT_AMOUNT_CHARGED,PERCENT_RENT,START_DATE,LCHG_TIME, 
LCHG_USER_ID,RCRE_TIME,RCRE_USER_ID,DEL_FLG,BANK_ID) 
 values( '42'  , 'KUK' , 'KU19' , '00080' ,'N', 49.50 , '33',sysdate,sysdate, 'AAY' ,sysdate, 'AAY' ,'N', '01' );

Comment: @Abid Didn't I explain it in the beginning itself? `'33,33'` is a string not a number. Anything between single quotes is a string. So, you need to use **TO_NUMBER** as I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers... You represent RENT_AMOUNT_CHARGED with a period for the decimal marker while PERCENT_RENT uses a coimma. Both in a string, but only one can be converted to a number as shown in the output you get in the error.

Why not just try putting a period in the pct just to try the suggestion? Setting NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS will not help as long as you have different makers for it in your two strings. You have to chose one way to specify your decimal point.

Comment: All combinations could be handled at individual SQL level.